# Java Read numbers from txt file

Tags: java, string, bufferedreader, trim

Let's assume we have a text file like this one:

```
#this is a config file for John's server


MAX_CLIENT=100

  # changed by Mary


TCP_PORT = 9000
```

And I have written the following code :

```
 this.reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
    String line;

    line = reader.readLine();
    while (line.length() != 0) {

        line = line.trim();
        if (line.contains("#") || line.contains("")) {
            line = reader.readLine();

        } else {
            if (line.contains("MAX_CLIENT=")) {
                line = line.replace("MAX_CLIENT=", "");
                this.clientmax = Integer.parseInt(line);
            }

            if (line.contains("TCP_PORT=")) {

                line = line.replace("TCP_Port=", "");
                tcp_port = Integer.parseInt(line);
            }

        }
    }
```

where clientmax and tcp_port are of type int.

Will clientmax and tcp_port receive their value for this code?

What should I do if I the text file changes a little bit to:

```
MAX_CLIENT=100# changed by Mary
```

containing a comment after the number.

ow,btw # represents the start of a comment.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a class designed for this purpose: [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)

This class handles comments for you so you don't have to worry about them.

You use it like this:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(new FileInputStream(filename));
```

Then you can extract properties form it using:

```
tcpPort = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("tcpPort"));
```

Or save using:

```
prop.setProperty("tcpPort", String.valueOf(tcpPort));
```

Comment: I know Properties handle comments that are complete lines, but does it handle trailing line comments?

Comment: I am curious too..if you have a text of format: MAX_CLIENT=100# changed by Mary. Will the property class select only the value 100 and nothing after it?

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't 100% fit for that purpose, but at the other side, what if you have string properties that contain the `#` character, the properties class even allows you to store arbery unicode characters and newlines in its properties. Having comments on the same line as a value is something that isn't done often because the trouble it gives when parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Use `line.startsWith("#")` instead of `line.contains("#")`

When you do this, keep in mind that you need to stop reading when you reach a comment character.